# MainActivity.kt doesn't recognise button by ID

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

**I'm struggling with very common problem, I think.
I've created a button in xml file and tagged it with ID. Then I wanted to make onClickListener in MainActivity.kt. But when I'm typing button's ID, it's marked red and it seems like Android Studio doesn't recognise it. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding project, but the problem still exist. Invalidate Caches/Restart didn't help as well.
Here's XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDateBicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#3D446C"
        android:text="Select Date"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**And here's *kotlin* code**

```
package com.example.ageinminutes

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val mybtn = findViewById<btnDateBicker>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to fetch by id, use **findViewById** method.

```
val myBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnDateBicker)
```

or

```
val myBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnDateBicker)
```

Another way to play with views in the kotlin file:

1. Try with synthetic binding, like just start writing few words of XML id in your kotlin file and android studio will attach that view for you. **[Deprecated after Android 11]**
2. Try with view binding or data binding, you just have to enable these settings in build.gradle file. **[More Robust way]**

Comment: I've tried synthetic binding. Also, I tired to call a text by ID but the IDE doesn't recognise any ID defined in XML Code. I tried all these methods before with no proper result.

Comment: Ohh man!, either you have deleted the Resource import or android studio didn't add by itself. By adding com.example.ageinminutes.R; in import will surely work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`val mybtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnDateBicker)`